# AC-DC voltage doubler rectifier

Tags: mosfet, rectifier, boost, mosfet-driver

I designed a 50 Watt voltage doubler rectifier with rated input 12 VAC and output 48 VDC. The circuit configuration and simulation result are presented in figure below.

[image: Circuit Configuration]

[image: Simulation results]

2 unit [IRFP460](http://www.vishay.com/docs/91237/91237.pdf) power MOSFET implemented in this rectifier as switching component. These switches are driven by [TLP250](http://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?pid=TLP250&lang=en&type=datasheet) with Vcc = 18 Volts.

[image: Configuration of MOSFET's driver]

I checked MOSFET's gate-to-source voltage (Vgs) and found that there is an unexpected transient voltage at rising and falling edge.

[image: Gate-Source Voltage]

What is the effect of this transient voltage to rectifier circuit? Can it affect the value of input current and output voltage?

This is full configuration of circuit.

[image: Boost Rectifier]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That transient is likely caused by the drain-gate capacitance - when the transistor switches on or off suddenly the drain jects charge into this capacitance and the gate gets a spike. You haven't shown your gate driver circuits so it's difficult to say for sure but this is what usually happens. Try reducing any series resistance to your gate to see if this reduces.

Comment: Output of TLP250 connected to MOSFET gate directly. I didn't put any series resistor. I edited the question, there is configuration circuit from driver to MOSFET.

Comment: What is the effect of that spike? I tested this rectifier with 1 Volt 50 Hz input and 46 Ohm resistive load, the DC output should be 4 Volt. But, i got very small DC output (about 100 mV), meanwhile the input current is very high (2.5 Amps).

Comment: @Sidqi without full and complete circuit diagrams I can't advise you.

Comment: Here's full configuration http://i.stack.imgur.com/FBu6k.png

Comment: When i disconnected TLP250 from MOSFET (gate terminal floating) then AC input adjusted to 1 Volt, i got 2.5 Amps input current and very hot MOSFET.

Comment: That would be normal - the gate is floating. The circuit isn't complete - what about the 18 volt supplies - where are they derived from? I suspect the problem is because you are not using properly isolated 18 volt supplies. How about some values on R, L and C too.

Comment: Two supplies are isolated. I use two unit 220/18 V transformer, diode rectifier, capacitor, etc.